# when I enter any alphabets in URL, it redirects me to 404 page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I have website that is created in WordPress. In the website I have so many CMS pages. I have a page for showing the listing of Properties. On this page I have address column that is a link, by clicking on that link user redirect to the details page for that property.

I am showing the list of the properties by a function that is calling from short-code. In the PHP code file, I am creating the links by using anchor tag something like this :

```
<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url').'/auction-detail/?id='.$auctions[$i]->id; ?>"><strong style="text-decoration:underline">Detail</strong></a>
```

This shows the URL like : mysite.com/auction-detail/?id=1234

This is working fine for me but now I don't want to show the link like this. I want crreate the SEF URLs, for that I want to show the address of the property in the URL like :

mysite.com/auction-detail/country-state-city

I have successfully created these type of URL by using form instead of anchor tag like :

```
<form action="<?php echo bloginfo('url').'/auction-detail/'.$address; ?>" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $auctions[$i]->id; ?>" />
   <input type="submit" value="Detail" name="Submit" id="frm1_submit" />
</form>
```

But now the problem is that WordPress redirects me to the "Not found, error 404" page.

I think this is the default WordPress feature because Not only for this page but for all pages if I enter any alphabet after the page name or post name then it does the same and throw me on 404 page.

Example : mysite.com/contact-us/

For the above URL if I type any alpahbet like : mysite.com/contact-us/abcd then it throws me on 404 page but if I type number after the page name then it stays on the same page like :
mysite.com/contact-us/1234

I have searched a lot and implement many things but notthing is working out.

Can anybody please provide the solution for this so that if I pass address after the page name like :

mysite.com/auction-detail/country-state-city

then it should stick or stay on this page only should not go to the 404 page.

The address can contain alphanumeric values, spaces and special characters.

Thanks in advance.

I have chosen the Permalink Settings as  Post name - mysite.com/sample-post/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create permalinks, but you're not doing it the right way.

Go to /wp-admin/options-permalink.php - this is where you change how your site handles links. For example, I use /%category%/%postname% to create SEO-friendly URLs. You might have to make your .htaccess file writable in order to do this.

Comment: I don't to create permalinks for my whole site, I just want to stop the redirection to 404 of wordpress for a particular page or post.

There is page auction-detail, for that I want that if I type any string after the page name like auction-detail/abcd, then it should not throw me to on the 404 page.

Please give me some idea that will this be possible by htaccess or from php code.